# Как отправлять сообщении в определенный момент времени telethon

Tags: python, telethon

Не могу понять как обернуть функцию, чтобы она отправляла в определённый момент времени какое либо сообщение

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import configparser
import threading
import schedule

config = configparser.ConfigParser()  # чтение из конфига
config.read("config.ini")
API_ID = config['Telegram']['api_id']  # можно получить с ссылки выше
API_HASH = config['Telegram']['api_hash']  # можно получить с ссылки выше
USER_NAME = config['Telegram']['username']  # Ваш ник в телеграмме

client = TelegramClient(USER_NAME, API_ID, API_HASH).start()

messages_group = {
    1: "Отправляю раз в 1 минуту",
    2: "Отправляю раз в 2 минуты"
}

group = ["name"]


class MessagesPerTime(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MessagesPerTime, self).__init__()
        for i in messages_group:
            schedule.every(i).seconds.do(lambda: self.send_message(messages_group[i])).tag(messages_group[i])

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()

    def send_message(self, message):
        for i in group:
            client.send_message(i, message=message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = MessagesPerTime()
    bot.start()
    try:
        client.run_until_disconnected()
    finally:
        client.disconnect()
```

Выдает ошибку

```
\venv\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py:94: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MessagesPerTime.send_message' was never awaited
  self._run_job(job)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

P.s. не силен в асинхронном программировании

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from threading import Thread
import schedule


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start():
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')


def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every().day.at('08:30').do(start)
    Thread(target=schedule_checker).start()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Данный код выполняет функцию `start()` каждый день в 08:30 утра.

`schedule.every(5).minutes.do(job)` - каждые 5 минут