# Как сделать запуск функции каждый день в 08:00?

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

Если добавить команду, то функция через у команду работает. Как сделать чтобы эта функция запускалась, скажем, каждый день в 08:00?

```
def data_r_new(message):
    
    core.log(message.chat, message.text)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATABASE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM dovidnyk WHERE strftime('%d-%m', data_r) = strftime('%d-%m', 'now')"
    cursor.execute(sql,)
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    for fn in result:
        sql = "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE status = True"
        cursor.execute(sql,)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        for i in result:
            dr = datetime.strptime(fn[6], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
            msg =  "<i> <u>ПІБ</u></i>:  <b>{} {} {}</b>\n" \
                   "<i> <u>Дата народження</u></i>:  <b>{}</b>\n".format(fn[3], fn[4], fn[5], dr)
            sent = bot.send_message(i[0], msg, reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вариант: Работает нормально с polling, но с flask не работает.

```
from multiprocessing import *
import schedule

def start_process():
    p1 = Process(target=P_schedule.start_schedule, args=()).start()

def start_schedule():
   schedule.every().day.at("08:00").do(data_r_new)
    
   while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

def data_r_new():
    ...... 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_process()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Второй вариант: Работает нормально с flask.

```
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler

def data_r_new():
    ...... 

scheduler = APScheduler()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not app.debug or os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') == 'true':
        scheduler.add_job(id ='data_r_mess_new', func = data_r_mess_new, trigger = 'cron', hour = 8, minute = 0, second = 0)
        scheduler.start()
```

ПС.  Строка `if not app.debug or os....` нужна для того чтобы не приходило сообщение два раза, когда во `flask` включен `debug=True`. Если `debug` не включен, эту строчку можно убрать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете запускать свои скрипты в определенное время через
[python-rq](https://python-rq.org). Эта библиотека довольно просто подключается:

```
from redis import Redis 
from rq import Queue 
q = Queue(connection=Redis())
```

И планируется:

```
q.enqueue_at(datetime(2021, 01, 20, 8, 0), data_r_new, message)
```

А с помощью функции `enqueue_in` можно задать интервал, через который функция будет выполняться

Библиотека имеет хорошую документацию, и не требует глубокого изучения. Является в какой-то степени альтернативой для известной celery.

Запускается так же отдельным процессом (для запуска с планировщиком необходимо задать дополнительный ключ):

```
rq worker --with-scheduler
```

P.S:
В качестве альтернативы так же можете посмотреть в сторону [dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io/guide.html#message-age-limits) (поддерживает приоритеты задач и их запуск через заданный промежуток времени)

.

Answer (score 1):

Как возможная альтернатива.

*Первое.* Вероятно, надо установить специальный модуль [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/). Он не входит в перечень стандартных модулей "из коробки".

```
$ pip install schedule
```

*Второе.* Добавить в программу следующее:

```
import schedule    
import time    
def job():    
    print("I'm working...")    
   
schedule.every().day.at("08:00").do(job) 

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Здесь - `job` - это ваша функцию, которую вы хотите выполнять в 8:00.

Есть еще модуль [shed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) из стандартной библиотеки, но там время идет в секундах от начала эпохи и придется повозиться, с тем чтобы добавлять задачу на 8:00.   Однако это может оказаться полезным упражнением и ничего дополнительно не надо устанавливать...

**=== Альтернатива альтернативе ===**
Используем модуль строенный модуль тайм [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) и смекалку :-).

```
import time

time.localtime()
Out[42]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2021, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=18, tm_hour=13, tm_min=7, tm_sec=22, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=18, tm_isdst=0)

time.localtime().tm_hour
Out[43]: 13
```

Как видите, несложно узнать текущее время, используя

```
.tm_hour .tm_min .tm_sec
```

например так:

```
import time

...
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    z = time.localtime()    
    if z.tm_hour == 8  and z.tm_min == 0  and tm_sec == 0:
        print("Бимба")
```

Comment: Я пробовал (щас проверяю такой метод) schedule но он блокирует все остальные функции бота если все в одном файле. Решил  разить на 2 файла. Сам бот запускается на flask, а рассылку отдельным файлом на polling. time я еще не пробовал, я так понимаю там в примере где три точки должна быть функция, то есть while True: это конец функции. Спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134

Comment: @Violet функция работает но есть минус, он блокирует перезапуск бота (бот тупо висит). К примеру если я добавляю нового пользователя (user_id), то бот автоматом перезапускается с новым id, чтобы пользователь мог работать с ботом. Бот закрытого типа, только одобренные пользователи.

Comment: использую данный код на vps, бот перезапускается cron'ом, ничего не висит и не блокирует. там же специально поток отдельный используется

Comment: @Violet я использую windows server 2016, когда  flask начинает перезапускаться после внесения изменений тупо начинает висит cmd. cmd не реагирует ни на одну команду, приходится вручную закрывать cmd и заново запускать бота.

Comment: попробуйте запускать ваш скрипт как службу

Comment: @Violet а как файл ру сделать службой, я искал раньше такое но не нашёл информацию как сделать службой

Comment: @13_Voin https://www.devdungeon.com/content/run-python-script-windows-service

Comment: @Violet Спасибо за ссылку. А не покажешь как можно сделать (где найти) команду чтобы перезагрузить эту службу (то есть перезапустить бот с помощью команды бота)

Comment: `net stop ..., net start ...`, но имейте в виду, что вызов остановки (с последующим стартом) службы бота из самого бота может привести к остановке без запуска, т.к. процесс завершается. Посмотрите в сторону потоков на счёт этого

Comment: @Violet привет, спасибо еще раз. Решил проблему с (бот тупо висит) решение внизу. И решил проблему вызов остановки (с последующим стартом) службы бота из самого бота 
        import subprocess
        filepath=r"C:\Bots\TD_Bot\Bot_R.bat"
        subprocess.Popen("start {}".format(filepath), shell=True)