# Отправка запланированных сообщений telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Мне необходима отправка сообщений по времени. Изучив материал, пришел к выводу, что этих строк должно хватить:

```
import time
import schedule
def plan_message():
    bot.send_message(айди юзера, 'Hello')
schedule.every().day.at("13:56").do(plan_message)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

И да, действительно, отправка происходит. Однако в таком случае бот не отвечает на любые другие сообщения. Если убрать строки

```py
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Сообщения юзера бот обрабатывать будет (и отвечать на них), но запланированные сообщения в таком случае не отправляются. Пробовал также удалить цикл `while`, оставив только строчку `schedule.run_pending()`, поместить цикл за бот пуллинг, но в обоих случаях бот не отправляет запланированные, но отвечает юзеру.

Comment: используйте потоки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134

Comment: окей, помогло. Но теперь бота невозможно остановить банальной комбинацией клавиш `ctrl + c`. Можно как-то решить проблему?