# Как сделать timer на python с проверкой(pytelegrambotapi)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

У меня есть метод, который обрабатывает кнопки:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def buttons(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Задание 1':
           <..Запуск таймера, 30 секунд..>
           <..Результат..>
        elif message.text == 'Задание 2':
           <..Запуск таймера, 60 секунд..>               
           <..Результат..>
```

Как создать два разных таймера и самое главное, как сделать проверку: если один запущен, то второй не может быть запущен, пока не кончится первый.

В предыдущем вопросе, который я создавал, было предложено создать класс с булевской переменной и через нее делать проверку. Если этот метод правильный, подскажите как это сделать.

Comment: Изучайте паттерны проектирования. Посмотрите [singleton](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/singleton) (там же есть пример реализации на python).

Comment: @ShamusRezol Благодарю, изучу эти данные

Comment: откуда берётся результат после истечения таймера?

Comment: @Violet Ждал вас на самом деле, вы в прошлый раз помогли очень.) Под результатом я имел ввиду, что запустился таймер, пользователь "отправился на задание", после того как таймер кончился, например он приходит с работы(задания) и получает какие-то награды. Это уже там личный код с запросами в бд, я не стал расписывать. Основное то, что нужно как-то запускать таймер по первой кнопке, чтобы он был независим от второй кнопки и наоборот. Также делать проверку, если запущен, то по повторному нажатию не создавался новый таймер. Я уже обдумывал как это связать со временем дня,но пока так и остановился

Comment: @Violet Еще я думал вариант, с bot.register_next_step_handler, чтобы запоминать время, а потом его сравнивать, но опять же не знаю правильного подхода.. Хочется сделать наиболее грамотно.

Comment: так может в сторону потоков посмотреть?

Comment: @Violet https://thecode.media/python-time-2/  вот это подойдет? Я просто пробовал один поток, но при при вызове команды снова запускался новый таймер. Многопоточный вариант еще не пробовал

Comment: Может это натолкнет вас на мысль реализации https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134

Comment: @Violet спасибо изучу сегодня

Comment: @Violet schedule мне определенно поможет, так как были задачи которые необходимо запускать в определенное время, спасибо, вы чуть опередили меня. Я правильно понимаю, что место name = main я смогу адаптировать этот код под условия if message == '' ? Но правда опять же schedule это не совсем таймер все таки, но я думаю попробую с ним решить свою задачу, описанную в вопросе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120817/discussion-between-eugene-kokorin-and-violet).