# telegram bot отправка по расписанию

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Как сделать отправку сообщений через день?

Код на коленях:

```
def minimain(message):
    if now == '16:27':
        bot.send_message((message.chat.id, f"Ваш баланс: {summ}р"))

while True: # этот цикл отсчитывает время. Он обязателен.
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Каждый день в 16:27?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Каждую неделю, но, написать пока не получилось на неделю)

Comment: В Вашем коде есть переменная `schedule`. Это одноимённый [модуль из PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/)?

Comment: Да, это именно этот модуль

Comment: Делал как-то бота для напоминаний. Там в базе данных хранился chat_id: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/97cb2e187bc52960b6a5be452da8c914f27c8595/telegram_bot_examples/reminder

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы используете модуль [`schedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/), то Вам подойдёт следующее правило:

```py
def job():
    bot.send_message(...)

schedule.every().monday.at('12:00').do(job)
```

Comment: А как указать время?

Comment: @АртемГолубев Если мы говорим о сообщении раз в неделю, то в какой день и в какое время Вы хотите отправить сообщение?

Comment: С начала недели в 12 часов утра

Comment: @АртемГолубев Неделя может начинаться и с воскресенья :) Предположу, что Вы хотите понедельник. Обновил ответ

Comment: не работает, использовал этот же код(только немного изменённый, ради проверки) 
```def job():
    bot.send_message(f"Ваш баланс: {summ}р")
    print ("Отправлено")
schedule.every().monday.at('16:56').do(job)```

Comment: @АртемГолубев Не работало, потому что нужно было передать аргумент `message` в функцию? Если из-за этого, то в планировщик можно передавать лямбду, например: `do(lambda: job('Test message')`.

Comment: Ошибку он не выдаёт, как и результат, может нужно указывать время по Мск? Или же что то не так в коде?

```def job(message):
    print ("Отправлено")
schedule.every().monday.at('17:13').do(lambda: job(f"Ваш баланс: {summ}р"))```

Comment: @АртемГолубев Вот полный пример, который я сейчас проверил: https://pastebin.com/TWmJCCW6. Время скрипт получает с ПК.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rr1F0Mtm

Comment: @АртемГолубев Вижу весь Ваш код. Постараюсь изменить, чтобы работало

Comment: Точно не знаю, но когда прописывается комманда "старт", нечего не происходит. Если убрать всё связанное с "def job", то всё будет работать