# Выполнение функции по времени python

Tags: python, время

У меня есть функция:

```
def send():
 # Какой-то код
```

Как можно вызвать эту функцию например, 9 июля 2021 в 10:12?

Comment: написать другую функцию, которая будет проверять время, и как только придет нужное, то вызовет вашу. Ну или поколдовать с планировщиком задач любимой ОС и внести туда скрипт с этой функцией на нужное время.

Comment: В вопросе нет ни слова про прерывания и про таймер. Зачем вы используете слова без понимания их значений?

Comment: Я работал с arduino и подобные действия выполнялиь таймером на миллис и прерываниями таймера

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134

Comment: А однократное выполнение?

Comment: Если через schedule - то после первого выполнения задачи делать cancel_job

Comment: Хорошо, я понял. А если мне надо, чтобы пользователь задал время, или оно установилось как системное + 3 секунды?

Comment: Если нужно выполнить действие через 3 секунды, проще создать отдельный поток (Thread), в нем сделать паузу на 3 секунды, потом выполнить действие.

Comment: Если чтобы пользователь указал время, то через schedule: допустим пользователь вводит `t = "10:30"`, потом выполнить `schedule.every().day.at(t).do(job)`.

Comment: Я использую datetime для получения текущего времени и рассылки сообщений, но пользователь может вводить своё время: schedule.every().minute.at(current_time).do(send_message(MESSAGE_TEXT)) current_time это секунды. Питону это не нравится: TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Comment: `send_message(MESSAGE_TEXT)` нужно перенести в отдельную функцию (или обернуть в лямбду), и эту функцию или лямбду передавать как параметр в do