# как отправлять сообщения через бота в ровно определенное время?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, schedule

Не могу осуществить отправку сообщений через каждые три часа. Пробовал с [schedule](https://tirinox.ru/schedule-cron-python/), но увы происходит краш:

```
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Понимаю, что сие процесс можно осуществить при помощи цикла While, но как это сделать, чтобы весь бот не лег?

Буду рад любому ответу в решении данного вопроса. В долгу не останусь.

**UPD:** Прошу прощения, что не приложил код сразу:

```
# Проверка времени рассылки #
async def check_time(m: types.Message):
    check_time = cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM send WHERE group_id = {m.chat.id}').fetchone()

    if check_time is None:
        cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO send VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (m.chat.id, 10800, m.date)) # 10800 - это время через которое должно быть отправлено время, в секундах
        conn.commit()

    if check_time is not None:
        check_time = check_time[1]

    return check_time


# Рассылка
async def send(m: types.Message):
    time_ = await check_time(m) # time_ - указывает через какое время будет отправлено сообщение (параметр может изменяться)

    await bot.send_message(chat_id= m.chat.id, text='text"') # именно это сообщение должно отправляться через промежуток времени time_


# ну, а это какие-то горе попытки (пытался сделать подобным этому - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1232276/)
def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(send) # тут ругается на то, что аргумента нэма.. send_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'm'
    Thread(target=schedule_checker).start()
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

По возможности всё расписал. Параметр *time_* нигде не затрагивается, но хочется, чтобы именно от него зависела отправка сообщений по времени.

**P.S:** Код немножко изменил, но все же это не помогло решению проблемы..

Comment: Это исключение выдает функция do(), когда первым аргументом передан не указатель на функцию/лямбду, а что-то другое. Код вы, к сожалению, не показали(даже банально строчку с вызовом schedule, так что конкретнее ничего здесь не сказать..

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134

Comment: Приведите пример кода, на котором у вас возникает проблема.

Comment: Код приложил, надеюсь, что он поможет