# Telegram bot на Python. Как отправить сообщение пользователю когда наступит определенная дата

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Друзья ситуация такая, имею такой код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['nap'])
def send_notification(message):
    if message.text == '/nap':
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        username = message.from_user.username
        bot.send_message(chat_id, f'{username} Я напомню Вам когда состоится матч') 
        if match_date == True:
            bot.send_message(chat_id, f'{napominalka}')  
        else:
            print('ass')
    schedule.every().day.at('14:10').do(match_date)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(60)
```

по идее он должен после того как пользователь напишет боту команду /nap запустить отслеживание дня матча и когда день матча совпадёт с реальной датой то бот напишет об этом пользователю.
Не понимаю как все правильно записать. Функция match_date выполняет сравнение даты с реальным временем.

```
def match_date():
    url = 'https://www.sports.ru/zenit/calendar/'
    page = requests.get(url)  # записываем в переменную page html код страницы
    clear_date = [] # объявили несколько списков
    parse_page = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser") #парсим страницу в формате хтмл
    parse_page = soup.findAll('td', class_="name-td alLeft bordR") #вычленяем их хтмл кода страницы нужный нам участок с играми зенита
    for data in parse_page:
        clear_date.append(data.text)
    clear_date.remove('Дата')
        #print(filteredNews)
    for data in clear_date:
        data2 = data.strip('\n')
        data2 = data2[:10]
        data3 = dt.datetime.strptime(data2, '%d.%m.%Y') # даты спарсеные с сайта
        current_date = str(date.today())
        current_date2 = current_date.split("-")
        current_date2.reverse()
        current_date3 = ".".join(current_date2)
        current_date4 = dt.datetime.strptime(current_date3, '%d.%m.%Y') # дата текущего дня в верном формате
        if current_date4 == current_date4:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

а функция Napominalka по идее должна отправить пользователю сообщение что сегодня день матча. Функцию прилагаю...

```
def napominalka():
    url = 'https://www.sports.ru/zenit/calendar/'
    page = requests.get(url)  # записываем в переменную page html код страницы
    filteredNews = [] # объявили несколько списков
    allNews = []
    new_games = []
    old_games = []
    new_games.clear()  #очистить список, т.к. в него вроде как много говна с предыдущих прогонов записывается
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser") #парсим страницу в формате хтмл
    allNews = soup.findAll('td', class_="name-td alLeft bordR") #вычленяем их хтмл кода страницы нужный нам участок с играми зенита
    for data in allNews:
        filteredNews.append(data.text)
    filteredNews.remove('Дата')
        #print(filteredNews)
    for data in filteredNews:
        n = str()
        data2 = data.strip('\n')
        time = data2[11:16]
        data2 = data2[:10]
        data3 = dt.datetime.strptime(data2, '%d.%m.%Y') # даты спарсеные с сайта
        current_date = str(date.today())
        current_date2 = current_date.split("-")
        current_date2.reverse()
        current_date3 = ".".join(current_date2)
        current_date4 = dt.datetime.strptime(current_date3, '%d.%m.%Y') # дата текущего дня в верном формате
        if data3 < current_date4:
            old_games.append(f'Зенит играл: {data2}')
        else:
            new_games.append(f' {data2} в {time}')
    if current_date4 == current_date4:
        n = f'Зенит играет сегодня {new_games[0]}'
    else:
        n = f'Зенит играет не сегодня'
    return n
```

И вот не могу понять как все это увязать чтобы бот следил за датой и в нужный день посылал пользователю сообщение что сегодня день матча.
P.S. я нубас с кодинге, конструктивную критику по коду с удовольствием принимаю, но в приоритете конечно решить вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sports.ru/zenit/calendar/'
users = {'2021-10-19': {1, 2}}

page = requests.get(url)
clear_date = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
parse_page = soup.findAll('td', class_="name-td alLeft bordR")

for data in parse_page:
    clear_date.append(data.text.strip('\n'))
clear_date.remove('Дата')

for data in clear_date:
    now = datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y'), '%d.%m.%Y').date()
    data_1 = datetime.strptime(data[:10], '%d.%m.%Y').date()

    if now == data_1:
        for i in users[now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]:
            print(f'текущая дата: {now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}\nотправка сообщения пользователю с id {i}:\n матч сегодня')
    if now < data_1:
        for i in users[now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]:
            print(f'текущая дата: {now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}\nотправка сообщения пользователю с id {i}:'
                  f'\n матч состоится {data_1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}')
    if now > data_1:
        for i in users[now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]:
            print(f'текущая дата: {now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}\nотправка сообщения пользователю с id {i}:'
                  f'\n матч прошёл {data_1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}')
```

добавление в словарь даты и id пользователей которым необходимо выполнить рассылку - пример.
желательно использовать БД, на крайний случай файл - это позволит хранить даты матчей и пользователей которые подписались на уведомления, а так же будет возможность забирать данные с сайта n раз в требуемый период.

в `schedule` запланируйте выполнение функции проверки словаря (пример) на наличие ключа с текущей датой.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134