# Как сделать отложенную отправку сообщений?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Подскажите, как сделать отложенную отправку сообщения, от имени бота в группы Телеграм, без ввода ид каждой группы.
Есть 15 групп, нужно чтобы по времени, например в 12ч и в 18ч, из кода брался текст и публиковал во все мои группы.

Comment: список с id групп, цикл по списку и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отправлять сообщении в определенный момент времени telethon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1232276/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-telethon)