# Не отправляется сообщение schedule, TeleBot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть код, который должен выводить сообщение в определенное время, но бот никак абсолютно не реагирует, ошибок нет.

```
def morning():
    def morning_code():
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Добрый вечер')
    schedule.every().day.at("19:00").do(morning_code)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможно сама функция morning() должна находиться в цикле while True, чтобы она постоянно работала и в нужный момент отработал остальной код

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134