# Планировка задач в боте на pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telebot, schedule

У меня есть довольно объёмный бот на pytelegrambotapi, и мне нужно добавить одну функцию, которая будет вызываться каждый день в N часов. К сожалению я совсем не представляю как подступиться к этой задаче. Возможно есть какая-то библиотека, позволяющая мне легко реализовать это? Я читал документацию schedule, но мне кажется schedule.run_pending() и bot.infinity_polling() будут несовместимы. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134

Answer (score 0):

```py
from threading import Timer

def setInterval(timer, task):
    isStop = task()
    if not isStop:
        Timer(timer, setInterval, [timer, task]).start()

def task():
    #Ваша логика
    return False # Если хотите остановить - True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setInterval(60 * 60 * n часов, task)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]