# Нужно написать telegram бота для уведомления пользователям

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Я написал парсер спектакля + словарь:

```
   import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pkteatr.ru/schedule'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
first_show = soup.find('p', class_='thumb__title').text.strip()


dictionary = {
    'Щелкунчик': ['Продолжительность спектакля: 1 час 40 минут', 'Антракта нет'],
    'Идиот': ['Продолжительность спектакля: 3 часа 30 минут', 'Начало антрактов: 20:15; 21:35'],
    #И так далее по словарю...
#print(first_show)
#print(dictionary [first_show][0])
#print(dictionary [first_show][1])
```

Как сделать так чтобы бот присылал инфу из переменной и соответственно из словаря ежедневно в 12:00?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234734/234134